# How to fill up a Pandas dataframe in a more concise manner?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use a few lists to fill up a dataframe. In this example, I have 3 columns (a, b, c) and I need to fill up a dataframe from all combinations of the 3:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
for a in np.linspace(1, 100, 20):
    for b in np.linspace(10, 1000, 10):
        for c in [1,4,9]:
            df = df.append({'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c}, ignore_index=True)
```

The above code works but uses as many for loops as the number of columns in the dataframe. Is there a more concise/more pythonic way to fill the dataframe up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the arrays and take the cartesian product. `itertools.product` provides a simple way to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

a = np.linspace(1, 100, 20)
b = np.linspace(10, 1000, 10)
c = [1, 4, 9]

df = pd.DataFrame(product(a, b, c), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

---

```
         a       b  c
0      1.0    10.0  1
1      1.0    10.0  4
2      1.0    10.0  9
3      1.0   120.0  1
4      1.0   120.0  4
..     ...     ... ..
595  100.0   890.0  4
596  100.0   890.0  9
597  100.0  1000.0  1
598  100.0  1000.0  4
599  100.0  1000.0  9

[600 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: the last line gives me the error: TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator. Maybe it's a version problem? I'm using Python 2.7.17, Pandas 0.23.4.

Comment: @Botond hmm possibly In that case you can replace the data argument with `[*product(a, b, c)]`

Comment: that gives an invalid syntax error. However, `list(product(a,b,c))` works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
import itertools

l=[i for i in itertools.product(np.linspace(1, 100, 20), np.linspace(10, 1000, 10), [1,4,9])]
df=pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```